# Can I pass a dictionary in List<T>

Tags: c#

I want to create a common method that returns an List of interface type of my tables. 

e.g. `return List<ITableInterface>`

My tables are

`public class Table1 : ITableInterface`

`public class Table2 : ITableInterface`

I thought of making a Dictionary such that

```
Dictionary<string, ITableInterface> = new Dictionary<string, ITableInterface>
{
  { "Table1", Table1 },
  { "Table2", Table2 }
};
```

Then, using dapper, i get all records of each table of which I return.

```
var tl = con.Query<T>("select * from " + tbl).ToList();
```

Where `<T>` is supposed by any of my tables. I just pass the string.
I know above code does not work but I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: What's the actual use or requirement for this? how you are getting `tbl`?

Comment: I want to dynamically get all data of all table of any DB. I know it sounds too huge but I don't want to hardcode and make a long list of method calls specifying the table names. The idea is, I just get the list of table names as strings, then I pass this list of table names to my common method then extract the data of each tables using Dapper. These tables then will be passed around the application. tbl would be the table name in my foreach.

Comment: when I say any DB, of any DB type e.g. MySql, MSSQL, Ms Access, etc.

Comment: Then your approach is wrong. Rather you should look into *Abstract  Factory Pattern*

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know though whether i have the luxury to do the ground work in time but thanks for the direction!

Comment: This question is loosely coupled together and you're not really explaining what you need or why you are using the things you're trying to use. Your dictionary variable has no name. You're treating a classname as an object (trying to put `Table1` into the dictionary. You're not explaining what the purpose of storing these tables in a collection is. Why a dictionary instead of a list? What does `ITableInterface` consist of, what it its purpose? Where is your generic `T` defined, and how does this relate to the `TableX` classes you're creating?

Comment: If you want to get the name of a class, just use the nameof keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof

Comment: @Lennart. Thanks for the link! Alhough it does not directly answer my question, it does makes it simpler instead of using a dictionary.

Comment: You can try making a List<ITableInterFace>, and then using nameof on each member of the list, and putting the names of the "tables" in a list. Afterwards, you can query each table for everything in it with this approach (assuming your table classes are complete and match the SQL Table names)

Comment: @Lennart,could you provide a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, ITableInterface> dict = new Dictionary<string, ITableInterface>
{
  { "Table1", new Table1() as ITableInterface },
  { "Table2", new Table2() as ITableInterface }
};

foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
{
     var table = dict.GetValueOrDefault(key);
     table?.  // do something (question mark is there for null protection)
}

// if you just want a list of all your tables this is it
var listOfTables = dict.Keys.Select(_ => dict.GetValueOrDefault(_)).ToList();
```

Comment: the Dictionary declarion will not compile actually as the class is being used like a variable instead of an actuall class. If i change it to

Comment: { "Table1", new Table1()}, i'm not sure how to pass the class as a type <T> to Query method.

Comment: aha ok you have to make sure that Table1 and Table2 are referred to as your interface. let me edit....

Comment: now your listOfTables will be a List<ITableInterface> :)

Comment: if this answered your questions, please mark it as so ;)

Comment: I have actually placed that in my code... Above the Dictionary declaration. :)

Comment: I mean select my answer as the answer in here so I get the points :)